Prove that sum of $\frac{z^n}{n}$ is not uniform
So I needed to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n/n, |z|<1$ does not have uniform convergence.
I had two proofs. Here is one. I said that a uniformly convergent series with uniformly continuous terms is also uniformly continuous, but all uniformly continuous functions on the unit disk are bounded, $-\log(1-z)$ is not bounded inside the unit disk, so it is not uniformly continuous so the series cannot have uniform convergence.
The prof said this was wrong
Is this true?

Looks OK to me,  but a better proof is to note that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}\frac   {(1-\frac 1 m)^{k}} {k}$ does not tend to $0$. Note that $(1-\frac 1 m)^{k} \ge (1-\frac 1 m)^{m}$ for $k \le m$.

Your proof is fine! What argument did your prof give for their claim it was wrong?

Your reasoning is fine. You do not need to know the explicit formula for the sum. It suffices to observe that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum{x^n\over n}=\infty.$

@Anne Bauval They wanted me to use a specific proof that they used. And they not told me after the fact. They did not seem to understand my proof. I feel like I have to quote the theorems back to them. Sometimes I feel like I am the one doing the teaching
